# Unable to view database using JSTFL

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp

I previously used scriplets in my JSP page to view the database but have been told that it is bad practice and that I should use JSTL. However whenever I try doing this, I am getting an error saying:

```html
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/car1"
```

I need help understanding the syntax (layout) of JSTL code and how I am able to use it to connect and view the database.

**JSP Page**

```js
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<sql:query var="owner" dataSource="jdbc/car1">
    Select * from owner
</sql:query>
    

<table border="1">
    <!-- column headers -->
    <tr>
        <c:forEach var="columnName" items="${owner.columnNames}">
            <th><c:out value="${columnName}"/></th>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    <!-- column data -->
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${owner.rowsByIndex}">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
                <td><c:out value="${column}"/></td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

**Database Info**

```html
jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/car1 [APP on APP]

drop table owner;
CREATE TABLE owner
(owner_id int,
car_name VARCHAR (7),
firstname CHAR (20),
lastname CHAR (20),
constraint pk_Student primary key (owner_id));

insert into owner
values (12345, 'Nissan', 'John', 'Barley');

insert into owner
values (54321, 'BMW', 'Mike', 'Henry');
```

Comment: How is your datasource (`jdbc/car1`) configured? It seems you are missing the JDBC driver library (in your case the `derby-[VERSION].jar`).

Comment: I don't understand sorry.